# Spilt javascript array to small javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am struggling with a problem. I want to Spilt javascript array to another javascript arrays using javascript. The array should be split the last element of the array. it means `['/Local1', 'Local1', 'Local']` and ['/Local2', 'Local2','Local'] should contain in `Local` array. ['/Forign1', 'Forign1', 'Forign'] and ['/Forign1', 'Forign1', 'Forign'] should be in `Forign` array.

I have mentioned the tried code below. But my code doesn't give me the expected output. What should I do to get the expected output?

```
exports.getMenu = function (selected, username) {
  const menu = [
      [
        ['/Local1', 'Local1', 'Local'],
        ['/Local2', 'Local2','Local'],
        ['/Forign1', 'Forign1', 'Forign'],
        ['/Forign2', 'Forign2','Forign'],
      ]
  ]

  const xxx = getMenuGroup(selected, menu);
}

function getMenuGroup(selected, input) {
  var result = input.reduce( (acc,[href,label,group]) => {
    if(!acc.hasOwnProperty(group))
       acc[group] = [];
    acc[group].push({
      href,
      label,
      active:(selected == href) ? ' active' : ''
    });
    return acc;
 },{});
 console.log(result);
 //return result;
}
```

Current Output:

```
[
  [
    { href: '/Local1', label: 'Local1', active: ' active' },
    { href: '/Local2', label: 'Local2', active: '' },
    { href: '/Forign1', label: 'Forign1', active: '' },
    { href: '/Forign2', label: 'Forign2', active: '' }
  ]
]
```

Expected output:

```
{
  Local: [
    { href: '/Local1', label: 'Local1', active: ' active' },
    { href: '/Local2', label: 'Local2', active: '' }
  ],
  Forign: [
    { href: '/Forign1', label: 'Forign1', active: '' },
    { href: '/Forign2', label: 'Forign2', active: '' }
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fairly straightforward `reduce` operation.

```js
const input = 
    [
      ['/Local1', 'Local1', 'Local'],
      ['/Local2', 'Local2','Local'],
      ['/Forign1', 'Forign1', 'Forign'],
      ['/Forign2', 'Forign2','Forign'],
    ];
    
 var selected = '/Local1'; 
 

var result = input.reduce( (acc,[href,label,group]) => {
   if(!acc.hasOwnProperty(group))
      acc[group] = [];
   acc[group].push({
     href,
     label,
     active:(selected == href) ? ' active' : ''
   });
   return acc;
},{});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I added your code to `getMenuGroup` function. But I am getting `{  '[object Object]': [ { href: [Object], label: [Object], active: '' } ] }` as output. What is my wrong there. I updated my quection with your answer.

Comment: I think In your `input` one `[ ]` is not there.

Comment: @user_v12 so make that `input[0].reduce(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing a single line in the processMenuGroup function.

```
function processMenuGroup(item, selected) {
             return {
                 'href': item[0],
                 'label': item[1],
                 'group': item[2],
                 'active': (selected == item[0]) ? ' active' : ''
             };
}
```

In particular, the line that sets the "group" property for each of the objects.